# AES Encryption/Decryption for Symbian and JAVA

Tags: java, aes, symbian

I am using AES for encryption and decryption both in JAVA and Symbian.

JAVA - ISO10126d2Padding
symbian - CPaddingNone
for small strings it's working.
but while trying to decrypt lengthy string in symbian which is encrypted in JAVA i am not able to decrypt entire string, after 16bytes getting wrong value. anybody have idea regarding this issue?

```
plain text : the padding should be done at the end of that last block with random bytes
Encrypted in Java : 6889f21d0f7abbefe6a85d079aacf7d9df4978d9ae3a97ab069bca29e9ff95baee07c60e60777396e31a338ffb35b09f933c66491efc394a03699ea466c9f8ca1cb12af932caae1b72ea45f1f3424ed7
Decrypted in Symbian : 
the padding shou\x04íÒ\x7FjZß€ˆÍ}fîŒƒ±ºi\x1D·Ê\x1AøÍ&ï¢HßùÛsæl\f
\x18\x10ýÃmZû“\x15ÂþýX\t$>ž ...
```

Comment: No clue, but since it's exactly 16 bytes and AES is a block cipher, I'm going to guess it has to do with the padding. Why are you configuring different padding on each end?

Comment: because in server side ISO10126d2Padding is used and it's not there in symbian so i am using CPaddingNone.

Comment: Are you using a base64 encrypt/decrypt on the sender/receiver?

Comment: even i compared values by encrypting this value in symbian java only starting values is same                                  symbian :   h‰ò\x1D\x0Fz»ïæ¨]\aš¬÷ÙçÖH ¼‰sBï¼x,ã¬Y~ß=ì®Ÿ\x11Gö<1\x13ê*\'M‚+Œ&N
 \"Æeñºl_´ÜªáAŽh¯€\x19–\x1 ...
JAVA    :   h‰ò\x1D\x0Fz»ïæ¨]\aš¬÷ÙßIxÙ®:—«\x06›Ê)éÿ•ºî\aÆ\x0E`ws–ã\x1A\x33û5°Ÿ“<fI\x1Eü9J\x03iž¤fÉøÊ\x1C
 ±*ù ...

Comment: @Tech Trip : No i am not using base64 using CAESEncryptor and CAESDecryptor class

Comment: My guess is that you're using the wrong flavor of options on one end or the other.  Generally the first block must be identified as such, and additional blocks must be identified as "continuing", so that the state of the encryptor/decryptor is carried over from one block to the next.

Comment: so how to correct it?? can you tel me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I clearly remember that there was a bug regarding to padding in Symbian S60 implementation of AES but with some coding there is a workaround for it. I will try to find the page where I read about it... unfortunately Nokia burned a lot of dev resources regarding to Symbian during the last years :(

Comment: @MrTJ: Thank you So much for your reply.Really i am stuck with this. it'll be a great help if you can post that link.

Comment: You're lucky, I found it. Even if it is not about AES you might want to read it, maybe you find something useful in it: http://jonmccune.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/symbian-os-v91-c-cryptography-apis-available/

Comment: i dint able to solve this issue, anybody else have suggestions on this?

Comment: I had done a post regarding the usage of AES API's in symbian. Here is the post : http://symbiangeek.flaminghorns.com/2008/04/using-symbian-cryptography-libraries-part-i

Comment: Thank you eminemence, i am using like this only but i am not able to decrypt complete message which is encrypted in JAVA using any of the padding available in symbian. there will be common AES encryption and decryption procedure in all the platforms right??